# Xcode: How should I organize my multi-window user-interface project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, window, nswindowcontroller

Note: Using Objective-C, Cocoa, and Xcode.

At first, I did all my programming in the AppDelegate and had all user-interface elements such as windows in the same '.xib' (nib file). This worked great at first, but then as my application became more advanced with more "features", everything became extremely cluttered and the file too long for my liking.

I'm now trying to progress. I'm wondering how I should (properly and efficiently) go about having a multi-window project? My plan was to have a .xib file for every window, and put only necessary things in the AppDelegate. I would then have a core file for all necessary calculations and such to be used in my application and a Main Controller file to control outlets and actions from all windows in my app. However, I'm quite new to Objective-C and have been running into SO many issues and problems trying to set up Window Controllers and stuff.

Am I even on the right path? Am I doing it wrong? How should I manage a multi-window user-interface application in Xcode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For multiple windows, I think it's best to use an NSWindowController for each, with it's associated xib file for the window. I'm not sure what you mean by "a Main Controller file to control outlets and actions from all windows" -- each window controller will have outlets to its own window. You can't connect outlets across multiple xib files. You can have one window in the MainMenu.xib file that you get by default when you create a project, and use that to launch other windows perhaps, but it's hard to offer any more specific advice without knowing how all your windows relate to each other.

**After Edit:**

If you want to open another window, have a menu item's action method be something like this:

```
    self.controller = [[WindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"WindowController"];
    [self.controller showWindow:nil];
```

Here, I have a property called controller to keep a strong reference to the new window controller. If you don't do that, the controller will be deallocated, so if you have multiple windows, that you want to show at the same time, you'll need properties to hold on to them.

Comment: Thanks for your input. That's what I mean. One main window (and the menu). The menu is where I will mostly call other windows to be opened. What's the best way to use another window's controller to instantiate the window (i.e. click "Open Window" in menu to open windowA of a separate xib/controller)?

Comment: Thanks so much! I have a "main" file which I'm going to use for outlets/actions from the main window (and main menu). I have a NSWindowController property in this "main" file which I used for self.controller for the strong reference. So when I want to bring up another window within a different xib file, I'll use that window's controller, too. I also had to add a object into the main xib and use that object for outlets/actions. Am I doing this correctly?*Most* of my windows won't interact with each other, although some might need to get and/or set values in fields in other windows.

Comment: Yeah, I think that sounds ok.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have marked your response as best/correct answer.